# Are differing shapes of the acromion congenital or acquired?

Tags: human-anatomy

In the human body, the [acromion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acromion) is located here:

[image]

There exist different shapes of acromion, at least 3:

[image]

The frequency varies according to the acromion type:

[image]

Some clinicians consider that there exist more than 3 types of acromion:

[image]

Are differing shapes of the acromion are congenital or acquired?

{1} says:

> Debate continues as to whether the differing shapes of the acromion are congenital or acquired. […] We conclude that the different shapes of acromion are, therefore, acquired as a response to traction forces applied via the coracoacromial ligament and are not congenital in origin.

However, this study was published 16 years ago. What is the current scientific consensus, if any, regarding whether differing shapes of the acromion are congenital or acquired?

---

References:

- {1} Shah, Nirav N., N. C. Bayliss, and Archie Malcolm. "Shape of the acromion: congenital or acquired—a macroscopic, radiographic, and microscopic study of acromion." Journal of Shoulder and Elbow Surgery 10, no. 4 (2001): 309-316. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2046701264133216154&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; http://doi.org/10.1067/mse.2001.114681; http://sci-hub.cc/10.1067/mse.2001.114681